# Delphi IDE and MySQL 32 and 64 bit versions

Tags: mysql, delphi, ide, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have seen references to this over the web, but can't seem to configure this correctly. I am using Delphi XE8

I am devloping a Delphi based 64-bit MySQL application for MySQL after installing MySQL 64-bit, which works fine.

However, I need to make design-time changes in the IDE, such as viewing tables, mapping db-aware controls to the fields, etc.

I initially installed the 64bit MySQL, not knowing that the 32-bit Delphi IDE would need the 32-bit MySQL for IDE developing/editing/inspecting.

So I don't think I can have both 32 AND 64 bit MySQL installed on the same machine using the same 3306 port (or maybe I can?).

Does this mean if i want to inspect or work in the 32 bit IDE environment that I can't use the 64 bit MySQL? I have already designed a database in the 64 bit MySQL.....

I saw references to adding the paths to the FDDrivers.ini files, but I can't seem to get this going.

Please any thoughts??
Doug

Comment: sharing a socket port between two applications is not possible under Windows (unless you use http.sys web server API, anyway this is not the point here); but you don't need to run a 32-bit MySQL server - a 64-bit MySQL server will work with both 32-bit and 64-bit clients.

Answer (score 4):

Delph needs neither a 32bit nor a 64bit MySQL server, it just needs the correct client libraries ("drivers"). This imnplies, that you can keep your 64bit MySQL server on port 3306 and just install the 32bit client libraries. This should install quite fine in parallel to your existing 64bit client libs.

Just to make that clear: A 32bit client can talk to a 64bit server and vice versa. Only the server needs a listening port.

Comment: Thank you, Eugen, I have the 32bit client, but I am unclear as to how to configure delphi in this case to use the 64bit version for run time and the 32bit version for design time. Have you any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I would assume this to be automatic: Windows will give the 64bit version if requested by a 64bit application and 32bit else. If not, you could just reference it via the application path and then drop the fitting version with your install (this is not good style).